# Building release project with references

Tags: winforms, build

I have a Winforms project with references to DLL's from subprojects. I need to build as release for production and debug normally. However when I switch to release build then I have to change all the references (because they are linked to debug version).

What should I be doing to be able to switch between debug and release easily?

Addendum: I add the reference by right clicking on reference and adding the file reference. The problem is I am getting a hard link to debug or release versions.

Comment: VS .Net? VS05\10\12 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove all of that hard links to the `BIN\DEBUG` folder of your projects.
Then go back on the `References` folder of you project, right click and select `Add References`
In the mask select `Projects` and double click the Sub-Project name.
The following image is from Visual Studio 2010, but the concept is the same for other IDE versions

[image]

In this way, you let the IDE switch automatically the compiler references between DEBUG and RELEASE projects folder when you change the build output

Comment: I see this works but only for projects that are subprojects of the solution. Is it possible to do this for projects that are not part of the solution?

Comment: Not sure, but you can work something out of the Pre-Build Event command line (Project Properties -> Build tab). You can use the predefined substitution macros called $OutDir that resolves to the BIN\DEBUG or BIN\RELEASE and use it to copy files in specific directory before compilation starts. [A reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Macros for Build Commands and Properties like this: $(Configuration) as the name of the current project configuration (for example, "Debug") rather then the absolute path.

Take a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to use a project reference -- which I thought I was doing. But perhaps I need to select the project instead of the dll.